# Sending mhtml emails - C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, mhtml

I have a requirement to send emails containing both text and Images.
So, I have .mhtml file that contains the content that needs to be emailed over.

I was using Chilkat for this, but in outlook 2007 it is showing the mhtml file as different attachments(html+images).

Can anyone suggest me some other component for sending mhtml emails.
FYI, I am using .Net 3.5

Also, I do not want to save the images on server before sending them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I use plain old native [`MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) class. This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916388/sending-inline-mhtml/938173#938173) can point you in right direction

**EDIT:** I built a similiar code some time ago, which captures an external HTML page, parse it's content, grab all external content (css, images, etc) and to send that through email, without saving anything on disk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the post at above link is using LinkedResource which needs all images to be saved physically on server, which I do not want :-(

Comment: That isn't entirely true: LinkedResource first argument is a stream, so your image can be stored at some database, for instance

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using an image as an embedded resource.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress(fromEmailAddress);
message.To.Add(toEmailAddress);
message.Subject = "Test Email";
message.Body = "body text\nblah\nblah";

string html = "<body><h1>html email</h1><img src=\"cid:Pic1\" /><hr />" + message.Body.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />") + "</body>";
AlternateView alternate = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
message.AlternateViews.Add(alternate);

Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SendEmailWithEmbeddedImage.myimage.gif")) {
    LinkedResource picture = new LinkedResource(stream, MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif);

    picture.ContentId = "pic1"; // a unique ID 
    alternate.LinkedResources.Add(picture);

    SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient();
    s.Host = emailHost;
    s.Port = emailPort;
    s.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailUser, emailPassword);
    s.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    s.Send(message);
}
}
```

Comment: As I am getting mhtml output from Aspose utility, I don't have control over Images' names so setting ContentId is not feasible in my case, which I suppose is the basis of using LinkedResource. Any other ideas?

Comment: @iniki could you not just pre-process the HTML content and replace the images' `src` with `cid` references and use the original content (file name or data URI) to generate the `LinkedResource`?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Net would be the one that you are looking for.<br/>
MailMessage is used to compose new mail.<br/>
SMTPClient is used to send mail.
NetworkCredentials would be used to attach username and password for making request to sending mail.
```

Coming to your question how to add images.

You need to set `isHtml=true`  for MailMessage

Since you want to send mail relative paths in the html won't work like `../directory/imagename.formate`
in such case you need to give completed path to the image location that's `websiteUrl/directory/imagename.formate`

To get complete Url dynamically you can use like this `Request.Uri.GetLeftParth(URIPartial.Authority)+VitrtualToAbsolute.getAbsolute("~")`

I'm not sure about last line since I have wrote directly over here. You just need to use it and have good luck ;-)

Comment: That does not answer how to send MHTML emails that have images embedded in the MHTML

Comment: Does't answer the question yet gets 25 from Community :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set the MIME type to `multipart/related`. Change the `MailMessage.Body` to include the content of the MHTML file in it. Finally add a new item to the `MailMessage.AlternateViews` collection to define the correct MIME type. The following link from MSDN has a very good example how to set it up:

[MailMessage.AlternateViews Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx)