# Keep collapse expand while exporting to MHTML in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to create a report with 'collapse-expand' feature and keep it "live" when exporting the report to MHTML ?

I try it without any success, I just wondering if there is any 'work around' way of doing it.
I didn't find any references on this issue over the web.

Comment: Did the MHTML work and the issue is it's not live?

Comment: I export the report to MHTML format, but then the collapse-expand icon isn't shown, and the report keep the last state of the collapse-expand (means that if the state was 'open', the exports present the data open, but without the collapse-expand icon)

Comment: Never seen this issue before. Does the service produce either collapse and /or  expand icon or picture when it's exported?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2791735/1685810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MHTML is an interpretation of the RDL language upon exporting a report definition.  I am not sure if many of the advanced options of SSRS you would be available to do with exporting (drill downs, collapsing, etc).  You can collapse with Excel though, I do know that.

Could you not develop an HTML page that calls to the server or else give the user direct access?  Different formats will do different things but the direct report will always have more power than an 'export' format of it.  Before going too far down the road of doing this I would ask: "Why do you need to do this?"  Is a certain user having to have it in a detached format from SSRS?

There are two things I can tell you you can do depending on your level of knowledge of code and what you want to accomplish:

1. You may embed the report in existing HTML as a  property.  It is similar to:

   < Form id="frmRender" action="http://(servername)/(webservicelocaleofreport) method="post" target="self">
2. You can code in a language of either C# or VB.NET a report viewer that can call to the webservice to VIEW the report live via SOAP web calls.